# Visual Studio Command Prompt Setting up path

Tags: .net

I have tried to set path for visual studio command prompt but I could not.I want to set visual studio command prompt path in visual studio 2010 c# professional for Windows 8 OS. What is the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio installs (beside other things) so called *Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)* with *correct path and environment variables settings*.

Try finding it by directly typing In the Start menu of Windows or by

*Start menu | All programs | Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 | Visual Studio Tools |* **Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)**

(You can see that there are *other* command prompts, too - some of them may be more appropriate for you.)

Under the hoof every of those consoles starts an *appropriate batch-file* (e.g. `vcvars32.bat`) called from the general `vcvarsall.bat` file.